# What should be in /src/main/webapp folder in gwt application builded with maven

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I've got old/legacy gwt application to maintain. Application is builded with maven. It's containing few submodules, like:

- Spring servlets/controllers project
- Dao and Entity project
- Gwt client code project
- Commons project

in gwt client code project (with WAR packaging) is build path declared: `/src/main/webapp`. accordingly to maven docs there should be:

> src/main/webapp    Web application sources

But what exacly that means? What should be in this project? Should there be a java bytecode as it is now? I am not a master of maven/gwt but it seems to be wrong, can anyone more experienced help me? Share with me his folders/files structure of gwt/maven project- espacially `webapp` folder.

This project is huge, so it will be great if You would share with me adequate example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's impossible to answer accurately without knowing more about your build.

Answer (score 1):

So, in my case we have also a huge project in GWT and my webapp folder contains mainly compiled GWT files for production, folders like META-INF, WEB-INF and my index.html with the references to the compiled *.js GWT file, which will be used when index.html requested by browser.